# How to replicate AES Encryption used by this online tool

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/

I am trying to replicate this encryption with c# using CBC but not getting the same results no matter what I try.

So far my code:

```
    private byte[] hex2bytes(string s)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();        
    }

private AesCryptoServiceProvider GetProvider(byte[] key)
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider result = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    result.BlockSize = 128;
    result.KeySize = 128;
    result.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    result.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    result.GenerateIV();
    //result.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    result.IV = hex2bytes("ad77d666311839f5665aeb2e42f64542");

    byte[] RealKey = GetKey(key, result);
    _key = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RealKey);
    result.Key = RealKey;
    // result.IV = RealKey;
    return result;
}

private byte[] GetKey(byte[] suggestedKey, SymmetricAlgorithm p)
{
    byte[] kRaw = suggestedKey;
    List<byte> kList = new List<byte>();

    for (int i = 0; i < p.LegalKeySizes[0].MinSize; i += 8)
    {
        kList.Add(kRaw[(i / 8) % kRaw.Length]);
    }
    byte[] k = kList.ToArray();
    return k;
}

/// <summary>
/// Encrpyts the sourceString, returns this result as an Aes encrpyted, BASE64 encoded string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plainSourceStringToEncrypt">a plain, Framework string (ASCII, null terminated)</param>
/// <param name="passPhrase">The pass phrase.</param>
/// <returns>
/// returns an Aes encrypted, BASE64 encoded string
/// </returns>
public string EncryptString(string plainSourceStringToEncrypt, string passPhrase)
{
    //Set up the encryption objects
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider acsp = GetProvider(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passPhrase)))
    {
        byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainSourceStringToEncrypt);
        ICryptoTransform ictE = acsp.CreateEncryptor();

        //Set up stream to contain the encryption
        MemoryStream msS = new MemoryStream();

        //Perform the encrpytion, storing output into the stream
        CryptoStream csS = new CryptoStream(msS, ictE, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        csS.Write(sourceBytes, 0, sourceBytes.Length);
        csS.FlushFinalBlock();

        //sourceBytes are now encrypted as an array of secure bytes
        byte[] encryptedBytes = msS.ToArray(); //.ToArray() is important, don't mess with the buffer
        var x = BitConverter.ToString(encryptedBytes);
        //return the encrypted bytes as a BASE64 encoded string
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Decrypts a BASE64 encoded string of encrypted data, returns a plain string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="base64StringToDecrypt">an Aes encrypted AND base64 encoded string</param>
/// <param name="passphrase">The passphrase.</param>
/// <returns>returns a plain string</returns>
public string DecryptString(string base64StringToDecrypt, string passphrase)
{
    //Set up the encryption objects
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider acsp = GetProvider(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passphrase)))
    {
        byte[] RawBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64StringToDecrypt);
        ICryptoTransform ictD = acsp.CreateDecryptor();

        //RawBytes now contains original byte array, still in Encrypted state

        //Decrypt into stream
        MemoryStream msD = new MemoryStream(RawBytes, 0, RawBytes.Length);
        CryptoStream csD = new CryptoStream(msD, ictD, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        //csD now contains original byte array, fully decrypted

        //return the content of msD as a regular string
        return (new StreamReader(csD)).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Before I dive in to this, any reason why you would copy that piece of crap?

Comment: hard to explain really lets say I can't change that :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so according to the description the key is padded with zero bytes. You are actually repeating key bytes. Both methods are of course completely insecure, a key should just consist of random bytes.

The IV seems to be calculated over the key bytes before it is padded, using SHA-1. I don't see anything about that in your code. Note that the IV should change each time the same key is used, and using the SHA-1 over the key is therefore insecure.

The padding is zero padding, up to the size of the block. This means that if your plaintext ends with a 00 byte that you will loose data. Padding is not mentioned, but I tested this by encrypting something and then decrypting it with the same key. It seems the padding bytes are still there. This is not insecure, but as it may lead to invalid plaintext, it is definitely wrong.

There is no authentication tag (e.g. HMAC) added, meaning that anybody can just change the ciphertext and get away with it. In the best case this will lead just to garbage on the other system. In the worst case (and this one is most likely) you will completely lose confidentiality as well. This is probably what you were trying to achieve in the first place.

I hope I have given you enough pointers to create an implementation - for learning purposes or to migrate away from the given code. If you are using random crap - no other word for this - from the Internet, you will however end up with zero security. I won't provide code, as I don't want this to proliferate.

Comment: ty for the pointers will accept that and make another question with the real problem.